# g++ error "file not found": It interprets command line argument string as a file

Tags: c++, g++

```
~/Documents$ g++ -std=c++11 -o Assignment1 filename.txt 10
```

It gets through assignment1, filename.txt, but when it gets to "10", it thinks it is a file name and states 10 can't be found, and it is an error. I have it declared as argv[2] in main.

Assignment1 is argv[0], filename.txt should be argv[1], and 10 should be argv[2].

If you need more information let me know.

Comment: You gotta compile before you run...C++ is not interpreted

Comment: `g++ -std=c++11 -o Assignment1 whateverfiles.cpp` then `./Assignment1 filename.txt 10`

Comment: Justin, that first line just says "fatal error": no input files

Comment: I have roughly 30 minutes of lifetime command line experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass your two arguments to the executable that gets built from your compiler/linker. The way you described what you are doing seems to indicate you are trying to run your program at the same time you are trying to build it.

Try breaking it up into two command lines.

g++ -std=c++11 -o Assignment1 **yourcode.cc**

./Assignment1 filename.txt 10

Comment: I don't quite understand, my Assignment is my cpp file.  g++ -std=c++11 -o Assignment2.cpp   is that incorrect?

Comment: g++ -std=c++11 -o Assignment2 Assignment2.cpp